# Parallel Transaction Sending on Program Deploy

Tags: solana-cli

After upgrading to Solana v1.16.1 CLI, program deploy command does not send the transactions in parallel leading to Blockhash not found timeouts. I have to downgrade to v1.14.19 to resolve. Not sure if there is a flag I'm missing or this is a known issue with the v1.16 CLI.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a legitimate bug, but I think it's due to the congestion control on the TPU on devnet. Since there are so few devnet validators, the unstaked QUIC streams get filled very quickly. You'll notice that testnet is much faster.

We may want to increase the number of unstaked streams for devnet. Please report this as an issue at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues